# Smarty - include file

Tags: html, smarty

I tried to include a tpl file using smarty include file like this,

```
{include file='file_name.tpl'}
```

its not working for me. Is it needed to include path name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path to templates before. So call `setTemplateDir` before rendering of your template.

More here: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl

Also as I can see Smarty allows to specify full path to template file inside of `include` directive. So even this is possible:

`{include file='file:/usr/local/share/templates/navigation.tpl'}`

But personally I would not recommend you to use this approach and stick to `setTemplateDir` and consistent place for templates in your app.

Little more information on that topic: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.tpl